# How to refer two schemas in single entity using ejb

Tags: jpa, ejb

I want to use two different schema in database, each schema has same set of Tables but data differs. How to use same entity two point different schemas in ejb.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: I created two schemas and table with the same name in both schemas. Later I created two Entities for both to access. But I want to access data from a single entity instead of two entities.

Comment: I think this is only possible if you define two separate persistence units

Comment: Do you have any sample example or links to refer